# Validate two Spinners in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spinner

I'm new to PrimeFaces and I want to validate two Spinner component.
For example, if the Spinner one has 6, I need that the Spinner two show the next number, 7 in this case.

This are my two Spinner components.

```
<p:spinner id="start" value="#{hbean.startTime}" min="06" max="24" size="10" maxlength="2"/>
<p:spinner id="end" value="#{hbean.endTime}" min="07" max="24" size="10" maxlength="2"/>
```

I had the following code in my bean but didn't work.

```
public int testNumb(int startNumb){
    endNumb= startNumb+ 1;
    return endNumb;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spinner can be used in combination with ajax. So you could send an ajax request whenever your first spinner value change.

```
<h:form>
     <p:spinner id="start" value="#{hbean.startTime}" min="06" max="24" size="10" maxlength="2">
        <p:ajax listener="#{hbean.updateEndTime()}" update="end" />
    </p:spinner>

    <p:spinner id="end" value="#{hbean.endTime}" min="07" max="24" size="10" maxlength="2"/>
</h:form>
```

The listener in your hbean:

```
public void updateEndTime(){
    endTime = startTime + 1;
}
```